# Search by skippng or not skipping files

Tags: bash, skip

I have the following code that starts with the file numer defined by `ist`, then skips `isk` files.  I would also like to have the ability to pass all files through (e.g. when `isk` is `0`).  Is there a neat way to do this?

```
ist=1; isk=2
grep --null -r -l "${isufx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "${fdir[@]}"  |
  sed -z "${ist}~${isk}!d"  |
  while IFS= read -rd '' fl; do
    printf '%s\n\n' "${grn}==> $fl <==${sgr}"
    grep -ni "${ictx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "$fl"
  done
```

Comment: Can't you do this with `ist=0` and `isk=1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the start to `0` or `1`, and skip to `1`.

```
$ seq 6 | sed '0~1!d'
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Have tried your suggestion with no problems.  Is it more natural for users to use `0` or `1` as start index?

Comment: It makes no difference when skip is 1. But for other skip values, it changes which ones are shown. E.g. `1~3` shows `1` and `4`, while `0~3` shows `3` and `6`.